# Pivoting rows into columns dynamically in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have data like the following in an Oracle database

```
select * from TABLE_1

ID       Field      Value
----     -----   -----
  1      name    Bob
  1      age     30
  1      gender  male
  2      name    Susan
  2      status  married
```

I need the result in below format

```
ID       NAME    AGE    GENDER  STATUS
----     -----   -----  ------  --------
  1      Bob      30     male 
  2      Susan                   married
```

I wrote a query

```
select  
   ID,  

    coalesce(sum(case when Field = 'name' then value end), 0) as "Name", 
    coalesce(sum(case when Field = 'age' then value end), 0) as "Age", 
    coalesce(sum(case when Field = 'gender' then value end), 0) as "Gender"
 from "TABLE_1"  
group by ID;
```

I am getting a conversion error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Column `value` is a string type (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`).
You can not `SUM` strings. Use another aggregate function, e.g. `MIN`. And you do not need `COALESCE`.

```
select  
   ID,  
    min(case when Field = 'name' then value end) as "Name", 
    min(case when Field = 'age' then value end) as "Age", 
    min(case when Field = 'gender' then value end) as "Gender",
    min(case when Field = 'status' then value end) as "Status"
 from "TABLE_1"  
group by ID;

        ID Name  Age   Gender Status
---------- ----- ----- ------ --------
         1 Bob   30    male
         2 Susan              married
```